# How to call another controller function in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two controllers.

one is

```
 public partial class CatalogController : BaseNopController
    {

 [NonAction]
        protected IEnumerable<ProductOverviewModel> PrepareProductOverviewModels(IEnumerable<Product> products, 
            bool preparePriceModel = true, bool preparePictureModel = true,
            int? productThumbPictureSize = null, bool prepareSpecificationAttributes = false,
            bool forceRedirectionAfterAddingToCart = false)
        {
 var models = new List<ProductOverviewModel>();
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                var model = new ProductOverviewModel()
                {
                    Id = product.Id,
                    Name = product.GetLocalized(x => x.Name),
                    ShortDescription = product.GetLocalized(x => x.ShortDescription),
                    FullDescription = product.GetLocalized(x => x.FullDescription),
                    SeName = product.GetSeName(),
                };

}
}
```

another one is

```
public class HireController : BaseNopController
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CheckData(string submitButton)
        {
            switch (submitButton)
            {
                case "Yes":

                   // I want to call  CatalogController  --> PrepareProductOverviewModels
                case "No":
                    return RedirectToRoute("detailform");
                default:
                    return RedirectToRoute("detailform");
            }

        }
}
```

Inside Hire controller --> CheckData function , I want to call CatalogController  -->PrepareProductOverviewModels(...)
How can I do it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `protected`, so unless your `HireController` derives from `CatalogController`, you can't call it. If, however, you put it in another class, such as a ViewModel class, and make it `public`, you can call it from your `HireController`.

It makes very little sense for that ViewModel to be `protected` or for it to be in your controller class.

Answer (score 0):

If you have methods that need to be shared between controllers then you should separate those out to a "helper" class and have both controllers call into that class.